# problem in multiple search criteria with dynamic sql and sql joins asp.net c# sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a search page with multiple search criteria and a different page show the search result. the problem i am facing is when two or more users(different pc or browser) search on that page the priviously searched results get affected by the newly searched result. basically the searched result of the privious user get replaced by the searched result of the last user when privious user click on paging or refresh the page. i have provided the code of the search page and search result page.

[image]

```
//code of the search criteria page
protected void btnRegularSrch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string strCondition = string.Empty;
            string strSql = string.Empty;
            string custGender = string.Empty;
            string custReli = string.Empty;
            string custCaste = string.Empty;
            string custMtonge = string.Empty;
            string custCountry = string.Empty;
            string custAge = string.Empty;
            string custMstate = string.Empty;

            strSql = "select * from tbl_CustomerInfo cust inner join tbl_Relig rel on rel.regid=cust.REGID inner join tbl_Locat loc on loc.regid=cust.REGID inner join tbl_Photos ph on ph.regid=cust.regid and cust.status=1 ";

            //gender
            if (Male.Checked)
            {
                custGender = "m";
            }
            else
            {
                custGender = "f";
            }
            strCondition += " where cust_gender='" + custGender + "'";

            //age
            if (drp_age_from.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                custAge = drp_age_from.SelectedItem.Text;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCondition))
                    strCondition += "and cust.cust_age between '" + drp_age_from.SelectedItem.Text + "' and '" + drp_age_to.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
                else
                    strCondition += "where cust.cust_age between '" + drp_age_from.SelectedItem.Text + "' and '" + drp_age_to.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
            }

            //religion
            if (ddlSearchReli.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                custReli = ddlSearchReli.SelectedItem.Text;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCondition))
                    strCondition += " and rel.Religion='" + custReli + "'";
                else
                    strCondition += " where rel.Religion='" + custReli + "'";
            }

            //caste
            if (DdlCaste2.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                custCaste = DdlCaste2.SelectedItem.Text;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCondition))
                    strCondition += " and rel.Caste='" + custCaste + "'";
                else
                    strCondition += " where rel.Caste='" + custCaste + "'";
            }
            //mothertonge
            if (ddlCommunty.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                custMtonge = ddlCommunty.SelectedItem.Text;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCondition))
                    strCondition += " and rel.MotherTongue='" + custMtonge + "'";
                else
                    strCondition += " where rel.MotherTongue='" + custMtonge + "'";
            }
            //country
            if (drp_country.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                custCountry = drp_country.SelectedItem.Text;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCondition))
                    strCondition += " and loc.Country='" + custCountry + "'";
                else
                    strCondition += " where loc.Country='" + custCountry + "'";
            }

            //marital status
            if (ddlMStatus.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                strCondition = strCondition + " and (";

                custMstate = ddlMStatus.SelectedItem.Text;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCondition))
                    strCondition += " cust.maritalstatus='" + custMstate + "'";
                else
                    strCondition += " where cust.maritalstatus='" + custMstate + "'";

                //strCondition = strCondition.TrimEnd(MyChar);
                strCondition = strCondition + ")";
            }

            strSql = strSql + strCondition;
            Response.Redirect("SearchResult.aspx?condition=" + Server.UrlEncode(Encrypt(strSql)));
        }



//code of the search result page
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con_str"].ConnectionString;
       Utility objUtil = new Utility();
        static string Condition;
        #region Private Properties
        private int CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                object objPage = ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
                int _CurrentPage = 0;
                if (objPage == null)
                {
                    _CurrentPage = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    _CurrentPage = (int)objPage;
                }
                return _CurrentPage;
            }
            set { ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value; }
        }
        private int fistIndex
        {
            get
            {

                int _FirstIndex = 0;
                if (ViewState["_FirstIndex"] == null)
                {
                    _FirstIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    _FirstIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["_FirstIndex"]);
                }
                return _FirstIndex;
            }
            set { ViewState["_FirstIndex"] = value; }
        }
        private int lastIndex
        {
            get
            {

                int _LastIndex = 0;
                if (ViewState["_LastIndex"] == null)
                {
                    _LastIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    _LastIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["_LastIndex"]);
                }
                return _LastIndex;
            }
            set { ViewState["_LastIndex"] = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region PagedDataSource
        PagedDataSource _PageDataSource = new PagedDataSource();
        #endregion


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               if (Request.QueryString["condition"] != null)
                {
                    Condition = objUtil.Decrypt(Request.QueryString["condition"]);

                    this.BindItemsList();
                }

            }
        }
        protected DataTable getDataTable()
        {
            DataUtility objUtil = new DataUtility();
            return objUtil.getDataTable(Condition);
            //rptViewBasicInfo.DataSource = dt;
            //rptViewBasicInfo.DataBind();
        }
        private void BindItemsList()
        {

            _PageDataSource.DataSource = this.getDataTable().DefaultView;
            _PageDataSource.AllowPaging = true;
            _PageDataSource.PageSize = 10;
            _PageDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
            ViewState["TotalPages"] = _PageDataSource.PageCount;

            _PageDataSource.PageCount;
            this.lbtnPrevious.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsFirstPage;
            this.lbtnNext.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsLastPage;


            Repeater1.DataSource = _PageDataSource;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            this.doPaging();
        }

        private void doPaging()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
            dt.Columns.Add("PageText");

            fistIndex = CurrentPage - 5;

            if (CurrentPage > 5)
            {
                lastIndex = CurrentPage + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                lastIndex = 10;
            }
            if (lastIndex > Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]))
            {
                lastIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]);
                fistIndex = lastIndex - 10;
            }

            if (fistIndex < 0)
            {
                fistIndex = 0;
            }

            for (int i = fistIndex; i < lastIndex; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = i;
                dr[1] = i + 1;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            this.dlPaging.DataSource = dt;
            this.dlPaging.DataBind();
        }
        //#endregion
        protected void lbtnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentPage -= 1;
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        protected void dlPaging_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Paging"))
            {
                CurrentPage = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                this.BindItemsList();
            }
        }
        protected void dlPaging_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lnkbtnPage = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnPaging");
            if (lnkbtnPage.CommandArgument.ToString() == CurrentPage.ToString())
            {
                lnkbtnPage.Enabled = false;
                lnkbtnPage.Style.Add("fone-size", "14px");
                lnkbtnPage.Font.Bold = true;
            }
        }
        protected void lbtnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentPage = (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]) - 1);
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        protected void lbtnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CurrentPage = 0;
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CurrentPage += 1;
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
```

Comment: What you have right now is a huge injection issue ([Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)). You *need* to parametrise that code using `Parameters.Add`.

Comment: Seeing sql-code and _click event code in the same code area............please read about layer separation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-web-application-architectures  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmeier/2008/09/06/layers-and-components/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On search result page, you declared the Condition variable to be static, so it behaves like a global variable and every time a user reached search result page, changes the value of Condition variable for all users.

Change this;

```
static string Condition;
```

To this;

```
string Condition;
```